# convert xlsx to keyed json

Tags: json, xlsx

I want to convert data from an excel .xlsx file to a keyed JSON structure.

This is an example of the data in my .xlsx file:

[image]

I want it to come out like this:

```
{
   "Tom": {
      "Gender": "M",
      "Mobile": 6154234123
   },
   "Harry": {
      "Gender": "M",
      "Mobile": 6243622345
   },
   "Jane": {
      "Gender": "F",
      "Mobile": 6134513245
   },
   "Mary": {
      "Gender": "F",
      "Mobile": 6928341234
   }
}
```

I am doing a web application where a user browse their excel file and it will output the above keyed json.
I have tried using SheetJS but it only came out as a non-keyed JSON structure.

```
function handleFile(e) {
  var files = e.target.files;
  var i,f;
  for (i = 0, f = files[i]; i != files.length; ++i) {
    var reader = new FileReader();
    var name = f.name;
    reader.onload = function(e) {
      var data = e.target.result;

      var workbook = XLSX.read(data, {type: 'binary'});

    /* DO SOMETHING WITH workbook HERE */     
    var first_sheet_name = workbook.SheetNames[0];
    /* Get worksheet */
    var worksheet = workbook.Sheets[first_sheet_name];
    console.log(JSON.stringify(XLSX.utils.sheet_to_json(worksheet, {range:"A1:C5"})));

    };
  reader.readAsBinaryString(f);
  }
}
input_dom_element.addEventListener('change', handleFile, false);
```

Comment: Have u tried anything so far. Please post the code.

Comment: I have tried using sheetJS but it didnt work out. Please see the edited question.